# I am trying to make a file upload form for my website, I have some code but it is not working

Tags: html, php, forms, code

I cannot get this to work am I doing something wrong?

```
  $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152) {
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
```

}
?>

```
  <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "image" />
     <input type = "submit"/>

     <ul>
        <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
        <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
        <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
     </ul>

  </form>
```

Comment: "I cannot get this to work". In what sense? What do you try precisely and what result did you get vs what did you expected?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.